# Is it possible to create a group dependency in JMS

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

Lets say I have following structure:

Article:

- name
- content
- galleries: array of Gallery

Gallery:

- name
- description
- media : array of Media
- thumbnail: Media

Media:

- name
- file

Now when I am serializing The article or something that contains a gallery I need to specify groups for all children like this:

```
            'groups' => [
                'All',
                'gallery' => [
                    'Details',
                    'thumbnail' => ['Basic'],
                ],
            ],
```

Now every time I add something to the gallery I need to go thorough all controllers and add the deep dependencies eg. After adding a largeThumbnail field:

```
            'groups' => [
                'All',
                'gallery' => [
                    'Details',
                    'thumbnail' => ['Basic'],
                    'largeThumbnail' => ['Basic'],
                ],
            ],
```

If I dont do it, or miss a controller, it will include "largeThumbnail" with group "Details" instead of "Basic" and cause a lot of databasse requests (since without Groups defined it will just follow the tree and add everything it finds) killing the performance.

Is there a way to tell JMS what groups an entities children should have when a specific group is used for parent?

In other words can I tell that if I used "Details" For Gallery than it should use "Basic" for Gallery->media, so I can simplify the above to just saying:

```
            'groups' => [
                'All',
                'gallery' => ['Details'],
            ],
```

And it would fill in `'thumbnail' => ['Basic'],` for me?